# Compile Vuetify tag after adding it to div using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js, babeljs

I'm trying to add a Vuetify tag (`<v-btn>Button</v-btn>`) as text using `innerHTML` function and then render it to a regular button/link, just like Vuetify does. Is it possible?